# Cucumber issue with DataTable and TestRunner giving error 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/options/FeatureOptions'

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I'm using cucumber/selenium/java and trying to run a test scenario with a TestRunner, but I am getting the error below. Looked into it and it seemed like adding a cucumber-core dependency might solve the problem. A new error then occurred with the DataTable. Here is the error without the cucumber-core dependency in the pom:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/core/options/FeatureOptions

at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2152)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.core.options.FeatureOptions
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 14 more
```

Here is my feature file code:

```
Feature: LoginFeature
  This deals with logging in

  Scenario: Log in with correct username

Given I navigate to the login page
And I enter the following login details:
  | username | password |
  | cukey    | passwoid |
And I click the login button
Then I should land on the newest page
```

Here's my step definitions:

```
package Steps;

import Base.BaseUtil;
import Pages.LoginPageObjeks;
import cucumber.api.DataTable;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MaStepdefs extends BaseUtil {
    private BaseUtil base;

    public MaStepdefs(BaseUtil base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @And("^I click the login button$")
    public void iClickTheLoginButton() throws Throwable {
        LoginPageObjeks page = new LoginPageObjeks(base.Driver);
        page.ClickLogin();

    }

    @Given("^I navigate to the login page$")
    public void iNavigateToTheLoginPage() throws Throwable {

        base.Driver.navigate().to("http://www.executeautomation.com/demosite/Login.html");

    }

    @And("^I enter the following login details:$")
    public void iEnterTheFollowingLoginDetails(DataTable table) throws Throwable {

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

        users = table.asList(User.class);

        LoginPageObjeks page = new LoginPageObjeks(base.Driver);

        for (User user : users) {
            page.Login(user.username, user.password);

            //base.Driver.findElement(By.name("UserName")).sendKeys(user.username);
            //base.Driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys(user.password);

            Thread.sleep(2000);


        }
    }
        @Then("^I should land on the newest page$")
        public void iShouldLandOnTheNewestPage () throws Throwable {
            Assert.assertEquals("It's not displayed", base.Driver.findElement(By.id("Initial")).isDisplayed(), true);
        }



    }

    class User {
        public String username;
        public String password;

        public User(String userName, String passWord) {
            username = userName;
            password = passWord;
        }
    }
```

Here's my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>ownCukes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->




    </dependencies>


</project>
```

And finally here's my TestRunner class:

```
package Runner;


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/features"}, glue = "Steps")

public class TestRunner {
}
```

After adding the cucumber-core dependency I get the error - 'java: cannot find symbol' for the DataTable. Is cucumber-core interfering with the DataTable? Should I have the cucumber-core at all? Can anybody help? Sorry it's a bit long winded I know.

Comment: Upgrade cucumber-java version to 4.2.6. Remove the duplicate entry for cucumber-junit

Comment: Thanks I've done this, I just needed a different version of cucumber-core too. I'm still getting an error regarding the DataTable though. I just opened a new question if you feel you can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591569/cucumber-datatable-error-io-cucumber-datatable-undefineddatatabletypeexception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cucumber DataTable Error - io.cucumber.datatable.UndefinedDataTableTypeException: Can't convert DataTable to cucumber.api.DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591569/cucumber-datatable-error-io-cucumber-datatable-undefineddatatabletypeexception)

Comment: Afaik you do not need to explicitly add cucumber-core as a dependency; it's a transitive dependency of `cucumber-java`.